# Can the Income Consumption Curve have a non smooth shape?

Tags: microeconomics

Can the Income Consumption Curve have a shape that is kinked?

Comment: Please ask separate questions separately.

Answer (score 3):

An easy example:

When the utility function is
$$
U(x,y) = \ln x + y
$$
and the prices are
$p_x = p_y = 1$, the IOC is kinked at income level $I=1$:
$$
(x,y) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\left( I, 0 \right) & \text{ if } I \leq 1 \\
\left( 1, I-1 \right) & \text{ if } 1 < I
\end{array}
\right.
$$

---

A more complicated example:

When the utility function is
$$
U(x,y) = \min\left(2x+2y,x+10\right)
$$
and the prices are
$p_x = 8$, $p_y = 6$,
the good $y$ exhibits inferior (and Giffen) behavior. The IOC is kinked at income levels 30 and 80:
$$
(x,y) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\left( 0, \frac{I}{6} \right) & \text{ if } I \leq 30 \\
\left( \frac{2I}{10} - 6, 8 - \frac{I}{10} \right) & \text{ if } 30 < I \leq 80 \\
\left( \frac{I}{8}, 0 \right) & \text{ if } 80 < I
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Comment: thank you, I posted a similar question which for some reason was down voted even though I wasn't seeking homework help. Can you help me with the question https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/39696/income-consumption-curve-to-find-preferences , I only needed to understand if my concept with respect to the ICC was correct or not in deriving that result!

Comment: @DARE2ZLATAN Thank you but I don't like reading handwritten notes, I do enough of that at work.

Comment: @DARE2ZLATAN Also, the question seems very specific. As such, it is unlikely to be useful for future visitors of the site, which is ultimately the goal of SEs.

Comment: The question that I asked in this thread was very general and I cannot present what I'm trying to think or implement without showing my working or the question which is why I thought you could understand what it is that I'm trying to ask exactly by referring to the original question.

Comment: @DARE2ZLATAN you can show your work by typing out the equations and text using markdown/Mathjax. Pictures should be reserved for graphs not equations and text.

Comment: ok, will keep that in mind.